# formet in 24 hour inn clock function

Tags: javascript, html, web, real-time-clock

Hello every one I am writing a abir John and want to find the clock  Javascript file

**That's code add in javascript file then link in index.html  file**

````
function clock(){
var hour = document.getElementById('hour');
var minute = document.getElementById('minute');
var seconds= document.getElementById('seconds');
var amp= document.getElementById('amp');

if(h>12){
    h =h-12;

    var am = "PM"
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to convert 24 hrs format to 12 hrs format.
If you want to convert your hour to 12 hours format you can take `% 12` on the current time.

If the time is 13 then `13 % 12 → 1`

time = 23 then `23 % 12 → 11`

time = 24, then `24 % 12 → 0`, if the time is 0, then change the time as 12.

```
 if(h>=12){
   h = h%12 || 12;
}
```